# How does AWS manage automatic KMS key rotation for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

In AWS. When you setup your RDS database, you can choose a KMS key for encryption.
That key can be setup to automatically rotate each year (e.g. the case for AWS managed keys).

*Manual rotation*

If you did it manually, you create a snapshot and restore it with a new KMS key
(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securing-data-in-amazon-rds-using-aws-kms-encryption/)

*Automatic rotation*

**The question: How does AWS manage automatic KMS key rotation for RDS?**

- It can't just recreate from snapshot without a scheduled downtime
- It can't just ignore it, as a rotated key no longer should be used for encryption, only decryption

Answer (score 0):

Per AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.Keys.html

Amazon RDS automatically integrates with AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) for key management.

AWS managed keys are KMS keys in your account that are created, managed, and used on your behalf by an AWS service that is integrated with AWS KMS. By default, the RDS AWS managed key (aws/rds) is used for encryption. You can't manage, rotate, or delete the RDS AWS managed key. For more information about AWS managed keys, see AWS managed keys in the AWS Key Management Service Developer Guide.

Edit to further add:

You can't share a snapshot that has been encrypted using the AWS managed key of the AWS account that shared the snapshot.

Comment: Yes Aws Managed keys cannot be managed by you. Still though, the are automatically rotated ones a year. You can also setup your own Customer Manage Keys for the same 1 year automatic rotation. And that is exatly the two cases this question is about.
Your link i.e. futher references: [Rotating AWS KMS keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html)